# Fundamental representations of $\mathfrak{gl}_3(\Bbb C)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I have just started to learn about the representation theory of $\mathfrak{gl}_3(\Bbb C)$ and am confused.

I have read of the fundamental weights $$\omega_1=(1,0,0),\omega_2=(1,1,0),\omega_3=(1,1,1)$$
and know that these correspond to the representations:
$$\Bbb C^3,\wedge^2\Bbb C^3,-$$

**Q1.** Does $\mathfrak{gl}_{n+1}(\Bbb C)$ have only $n$ fundamental reps, although it has $n+1$ fundamental weights [where $\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}(\Bbb C)$ has one fewer since $\epsilon_1+\dots+\epsilon_n=0$] - Then $\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ have the same representation spaces for the fundamental reps?

**Q2.** Do all finite dimensional highest weight representations of $\mathfrak{gl}_3(\Bbb C)$ arise as subrepresentations of a tensor product of the fundamental representations?

**Q3.** Then, in terms of the fundamental representations, where does the irreducible representation corresponding to the dominant weight $\lambda=(2,1,0)$ live. i.e $V(2,1,0)$.

A guess would be that since $\lambda = \omega_1+\omega_2$, perhaps it lives in $\Bbb C^3\otimes \wedge^2\Bbb C^2$? I believe that two highest weight representations $V,W$ with highest weights $\lambda,\mu$ respectively make $V\otimes W$ have highest weight $\lambda+\mu$?

Comment: You are correct about the highest weight of a tensor product. There are a lot of questions here, and it might be better to split them up. But there are a few things to note: There is not a "the" representation corresponding to a given weight. What I assume you mean is the irreducible representation with that weight? But whether it is irreducible is not dependent on the weight being dominant (this is instead what determines if there is a finite dimensional irreducible with that weight).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Do you know the dimension of $V(\omega_1+\omega_2)$ perhaps? If so I can maybe make some more progress, and split the question up.

Comment: To get the dimension of an irrep like this, first twist by the determinant to get an irrep of $sl_3$ (this is unnecessary for this weight). Then the dimension is given by Weyl's dimension formula, which for type $A_2$ like here gives that the dimension of the irrep of highest weight $a\omega_1 + b\omega_2$ is $\frac{(a+1)(b+1)(a+b+2)}{2}$.